# Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 127.0.0.1:3306 failed: port is already allocated. on docker run command

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a Docker container of a Node application which connects to a MySQL database. The database is hosted in my localhost outside the container.

First, I tried to run it by the command `docker run -p 3010:80 nigel/insideroil`. The process started normally, compiling everything, but I was getting the following error when the application was trying to connect to the database:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:80:20)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
    at Handshake._callback (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:361:14)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (/usr/src/insider_oil/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:420:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1280:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

On my research, I found that the error can be related to the access of external ports, as mentioned in this link https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports.

So, I tried to run the command passing another argument like this: `docker run -p 3010:80 -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 nigel/insideroil`. But, now, the error is:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cocky_wilson (c702c7f659ee766ba11993ed6b2c3ce851f6a6cced3d2c04a31bb578a11b2b40): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 127.0.0.1:3306 failed: port is already allocated.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `-p` redirects a port on your local machine to one inside (when someone accesses 127.0.0.1:3306, it's forwarded to docker). What you need is something else, a way of connecting to your local machine from the outside. If you have a name for 127.0.0.1 or a better IP address, use it instead. That's the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MatthieuBrucher. The address 127.0.0.1 is actually my localhost where my development db is hosted. What could be a better way to access it from a docker container?

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 is the default address for localhost, which for docker would be... docker itself. You have another IP address usually.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the documentation first: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: If you really need to use 127.0.0.1:3306 to connect MySQL, you must not use -p flag when runs app container, instead, you should use —net=host. Just like: docker run -tid —net=host ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an access to a port on your host machine from a container, you should use the host IP address (not 127.0.0.1). And of course, DB should listen at the host IP address too (not 127.0.0.1).

Or run DB inside container too and use direct connect via names.